# Extracting values from string -> group result

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I would like to extract some decimal numbers in a string -> group the strings and sum the values.

I get the strings from a private API. They look something like this:

```
var foo = new List<string>()
              {
                  "+0.9 A / +0.62 B",
                  "+0.9 A / +0.62 B",
                  "+0.9 A / +0.62 B",
                  "+1.2 C",
                  "+1.2 C",
                  "+2.0% D",
                  "+2.0% D"
              }.GroupBy(x => x).ToList();

foreach (var group in foo)
{
    foreach (var str in group)
    {
        //...?       
    }
}
```

Desired result:

```
"+2.7 A / +1.86 B",
"+2,4 C",
"+4.0% D"
```

I guess that this has to be solved using regex. I don't know how to create a pattern,  but my best bet is something like `\+\d+\.?\d*`. It might be on the right track, but I need your help finishing it. For example, it doesn't take the possible "%" in to consideration ("+2.0%").

Comment: Can there be a decimal starting with `-`? What happens when you have a line like `"+0.9 A / +0.62 C"`?

Comment: @L.B 1: No. 2: Sum the numbers as usual. The letter doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like a somewhat odd thing to do but this should be pretty close (generates +4% on the last line rather than 4.0%):

```
        var r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<Num>[+-]+[\d]+.[\d]+)");
        foreach (var g in foo) {
            var st = g.First();
            var mt = r.Matches(st);
            var sums = new double[mt.Count];
            foreach (var l in g) {
                var m = r.Matches(l);
                for (var i = 0; i < m.Count; i++) {
                    double d;
                    if (double.TryParse(m[i].Value, out d)) {
                        sums[i] += d;
                        }
                    }
                }
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var start = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < mt.Count; i++) {
                sb.Append(st.Substring(start, mt[i].Index - start));
                if (sums[i] >= 0.0) { sb.Append("+"); }
                else                { sb.Append("-"); }
                sb.Append(sums[i]);
                start = mt[i].Index + mt[i].Length;
                }
            sb.AppendLine(st.Substring(start));
            Console.Write(sb.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with another solution, but I'll accept this since it does what I'm asking for.

Comment: If you are willing it might be interesting if you posted your solutions so that others searching for answers later would have multiple options to review.

Comment: Yeah, I'll add it. Noticed a bug. Posting later :)